# How to Display "No More Data" message after Button click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, buttonclick

I want to display a "Sorry! No More data to display" after button click with the help of JavaScript. Please have look at before button click and after button click images.

[image: Button Image]

[image: Message that should be display after button click in place of button]

I am using following Javascript function but it is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".Load_More_Button").click(function(){
      document.getElementById('noMoreDiv').style.display = "block"
    
});
```

and related html

```
<div id="noMoreDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > Sorry! No more data to display!</div>    <button class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 Load_More_Button"> LOAD MORE POSTS </button>
```

Please advise me how I can achieve this target.

Comment: i have put your code in my page it works, can you please update if any error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Assume you are jQuery... Make use of `$(..).hide();` and `$(..).show();`. this will automate the css `display` feature.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Load_More_Button").click(function() {
    $('#noMoreDiv').show();
    $('.Load_More_Button').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="noMoreDiv" style="display:none;" class="answer_list">Sorry! No more data to display!</div>
<button class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 Load_More_Button">LOAD MORE POSTS</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".Load_More_Button").click(function(){
      $('#noMoreDiv').show();   // this will make your div visible
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('noMoreDiv').innerHtml = "Sorry! No more data to display!".
```

Make your div empty and set the text by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Load_More_Button").click(function() {
    $loadButton = $(this);
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      if (data.content) {
        //append your content
      }
      if (!data.more) {
        $loadButton.hide();
        $('#noMoreDiv').show();
      }
    });


  });
});
```